# Call program with non-standard ascii values as arguments in shell script

Tags: shell, hex, byte, ascii

I have a question that may sound weird.

I need to call a program with some non-standard ascii chars as arguments like:
./progname º ÿ ÿ ¿

It needs to be these chars because these chars  are the following hex values: 0xba 0xff 0xff and 0xbf according to the extended ascii tables I found online. My problem is that when I copy the characters from a website (or from anywhere else) instead of copying the 1 byte value it copies it as unicode (or so i think) which is more then 1 byte.

I need to be able to call:
./progname º ÿ ÿ ¿
from a shell script, where º ÿ ÿ ¿ are the 1 byte ascii values and not the unicode (or whatever is is) values.

Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks

Comment: please include a small demo of your problem that we can run at home. Are you saying you can't pass in `0xba `0xff` as arguments? Many cmd-line tools require special environ vars to able to process non-English lang data. searching for info on the `LANG` set of variables may help. Finally, not all unix/Linux are the not the same in the support of LANG vars let alone more advanced char sets like unicode., so may not be possible to do what you want, except for the easiest cases. Good luck.

Comment: A quick primer on character sets: ASCII only covers characters for 0-127; various 8-bit character sets assigned particular meanings to 128-255. One of them, ISO-8859-1, includes the 4 characters you mention and is probably the "extended ascii table" you saw. Unicode assigns an abstract integer value to each character, without specifying what byte sequence to use. The first 255 characters of Unicode correspond to ISO-8859-1. The multi-byte sequence you saw is probably the UTF-8 encoding for the Unicode characters above 127: `ÿ`, for example, is 0xc3 0xbf.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm always confused by the notion of character -encodings/-sets and how unicode/utf/etc relate to eachother. I managed to solve my problem. The problem was that if I copy:
./progname º ÿ ÿ ¿. into the command line, then rather then copying the arguments as 1 byte values as listed in the 'extended ascii table', It would copy a multi-byte sequence. My solution was to do: ./progname $(printf "\xbf") $(printf "\ff") $(printf "\xff") $(printf "\xba"). This would print the arguments as 1 byte.